# Images from media gallery not getting added to revolution slider module in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, slider

I have revolution slider installed on magento 2 framework for my website. Whenever i try to edit the revolution slider ready module and try to replace images from media library, the "add selected" button does not work. It does not add images to the slider. However the images are being replaced successfully from object library.

In developer mode it shows this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

can anyone guide if the error related to revolution slider or any other issue.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Can you add the full error code and a screenshot? Is this a third-party extension?

Comment: Yes it is third party extention https://nwdthemes.com/extensions/slider-revolution

Comment: The error is shown in google developer console

Comment: Did you contact their support?

Comment: Yes, they havent yet replied

Comment: Same issue - any news about it?